# Draw a line in WPF with them backgroundworker

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, line, backgroundworker

I'm new to C# and WPF programming, so this might be a silly question, but there's something I'm forgetting that I can't figure out. I have a mainwindow with a button and a usercontrol. I want to draw lines in the usercontrol, but I want to draw them in the mainwindow only when I press the button. I have also created a button in the user control for testing, which should also call the function for drawing, which it also does. Only when pressing the button in the main window nothing happens.

`Mainwindow`

```
namespace Test_Punkte
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        UserControl1 control1;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            control1 = new UserControl1();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //control1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { control1.drawing(); }));
            control1.drawing();
            OnPropertyChanged("Button");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="Test_Punkte.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Punkte"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="49.439" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="351.363" Width="195.74" Click="Button_Click" Margin="10,359.561,586.26,10"/>
        <local:UserControl1 Margin="191.789,0,120.502,197.587"></local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Usercontrol`

````
namespace Test_Punkte
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Random ran = new Random();
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public void drawing()
        {
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            //Thread.Sleep(100);

        }

        public void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    int x_mem = 3;
                    int y_mem = 3;
                    for (int i = 3; i < 200; i++)
                    {
                        int x = ran.Next(200);
                        int y = i;

                        Line myLine2 = new Line();
                        myLine2.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
                        myLine2.X1 = y_mem;
                        myLine2.X2 = y;
                        myLine2.Y1 = x_mem;
                        myLine2.Y2 = x;
                        myLine2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                        myLine2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                        myLine2.StrokeThickness = 1;
                        can.Children.Add(myLine2);

                        x_mem = x;
                        y_mem = y;
                    }
                }
               ));
            
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            drawing();
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Completed" + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
        }


        void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("finish " + e.Result);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test_Punkte.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Punkte"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="400" Width="400">
    <Canvas x:Name="can" Width="400" Height="400">
        <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click" Height="31.256" Canvas.Left="289.686" Canvas.Top="10" Width="73.543"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```
````

Comment: Remove the control1 member from the MainWindow class and do not create an instance of UserControl1 in the MainWindow constructor. Then add `x:Name="control1"` to the `<local:UserControl1 .../>` declaration in XAML. Later, find better names.

Comment: It's also unclear why your Window and UserControl classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged. `OnPropertyChanged("Button");` is pointless, since there is no Button property.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I wasted two days of my life on it :D